# Angular 2 - What to do if modules need each other

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a case, where I have two modules, who have there own Pipe-definitions. One Module is a customer module, the other a product module. In products I want to use customer pipes and vice versa.

If modules in Angular 2 import each other like the following:

Example Root Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, AModule, BModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Example Module B:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BModule],
    declarations: [

        ],
        exports: []
})
export class AModule { }
```

Example Module A:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [AModule],
    declarations: [

        ],
        exports: []
})
export class BModule { }
```

The browser throws an error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module
>   'BModule'

I could create a SharedModule, that declares both Pipes and import that module into A and BModule. But this would not be SOLID anymore, because customer pipes and product pipes just *belong* into there own module and not in another shared module.

Any proposals?
I googled, but did not find anything :(

Comment: Do you have them in the same file?

Comment: Just create a shared module that you can use from any other module.

Comment: Maye extract that part of code that needs sharing with both modules into a shared module ...

Comment: Yeah - the idea with the shared module works and I already said this in my question. Problematically is, that if I put a customer and a product pipe in a shared module, I put customer and product regarding stuff in ONE module. This hurts SOLID... I solved my problem in this way, but its not a nice way. :(

Comment: @DavidElsner you don`t need to put customer and product in one shared module, you can of course introduce two shared modules (one for each) to stay with SOLID

Comment: Yeah... i guess I have too... though there  was a nicer approach  :)